# Can't compile objective c app using GNUStep

Tags: objective-c, gcc, gnustep

I've downloaded gnustep core \ gnustep system (for Windows) and come example apps. When i run the gnustep shell from  start>all program> GNUstep> shell, navigate to the folder containing en example makefile and type make, i get the following error :

Compiling file main.m
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found

so basically i can't get anything to build. 
I get the same error when i type gcc -v. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting that error because GNUStep can't find the compiler.  You need to also install the developer package ([GNUStep Devel](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html)).